# Why's my response coming back correctly the first log but later on it changes to a 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'm facing a very weird issue where my response comes back correctly during the first log but later on it changes to a 1 when the `console.log(data);` logs data to the console.

The screenshot shows the pattern:

[image]

If you expand the very first array underneath where it says `data below from userEffect inside Gallery.js` , the data shows up as intended

Then there's the response array from `App.js` which also appears as intended.

Lastly, the response magically gets converted to a `1` from inside `Gallery.js` and I'm not sure how.  I've ran out of options on how to troubleshoot this and resolve it where it doesn't get converted to a `1`.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm open to any code improvements and any other suggestions for better practice :).

Here's `App.js`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../../sass/HomePage/homePage.scss';
import LoginRegister from "./LoginRegister/LoginRegister";
import Gallery from "./Gallery/Gallery";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const App = () => {
    const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);
    let { push } = useHistory();
    let authToken = Cookies.get('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        getUploads();
    },[])

    function getUploads() {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }

        axios.get('http://localhost:8005/api/get-uploads', {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                let uData = uploadsData.push(resp)
                setUploadsData(uData);
                console.log(uploadsData);
                if (authToken !== null) {
                    push('/gallery');
                } else {
                    console.log("User's NOT authenticated, returning to login view");
                    push('/');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginRegister} />
                <Route component={() => <Gallery data={uploadsData}/>} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App/></Router>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Here's `Gallery.js`:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const Gallery = ( {data} ) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("FROM App.js INSIDE Gallery.js");
        console.log(data);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </>
    );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The push method of array always returns the new length of the array( in your case is 1) which you are setting it to the `uploadsData` state.

```
let uData = uploadsData.push(resp)
setUploadsData(uData);
```

And you should never set the value of the state like that(mutable). Instead you should update the state immutably like this:

```
let uData = [...uploadsData,resp];
setUploadsData(uData);
```

Comment: glad to hear it!